# Query many to many relationship with DetachedCriteria

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Right now I have 3 tables in database:

```
Table A:
id:
...

Table B:
id:
...

Table C:
A_id:
B_id:
...
```

The mapped object is like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="A")
Class A{
    Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinTable(name="C",joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="A_id")},inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="B_id")})
    List<B> Bs;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="B")
Class B{
    Long id;
}
```

Now I would like to use DetachedCriteria to do a query to find all A entities with A.Bs contains a specific B. Is it possible to do the query with DetachedCriteria.

I think the sql should be

```
Select A.* 
From A inner join C on A.id=C.A_id inner join B on B.id=C.B_id 
Where B.id=?
```

Thanks a lot! Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In HQL, it would simply be

```
select a from A a inner join a.bs b where b.id = :id
```

And it translates directly to criteria:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(A.class, "a");
c.createAlias("a.bs", "b");
c.add(Restrictions.eq("b.id", bId);
```

As always, the link to [the documentation explaining it](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-associations).